# Code seasonal_decompose from statsmodels with only native python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, trend

I need to get the same result of the following code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

# the values are just a list of numbers ([589, 561, 640, 656, ...])
values =  list(df['Monthly milk production'].as_matrix().transpose())

trend = seasonal_decompose(values, freq = 12).trend
```

but without using the statsmodels module

I wonder if there is just a formula that computes the trend values so I can replace that formula with native python.

Comment: I need in this way due spark workers cannot import the statsmodels module in a UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the actual code of statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.

It is online at https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py

All in Python

Comment: Well, it's numpy for speed and linear algebra, and as extras pandas for datetime handling and interface and matplotlib for plotting.The part in statsmodels is "all in Python". But I guess you could rewrite it to work with plain Python lists and loops instead of arrays and C/Fortran-loops.

Comment: I tried to replace the source code even with the numpy function, but I couldn't find the definition of the function signal.sigtools._correlateND wich is neccessary.

Comment: You should be able to use numpy.correlate or numpy.convolve, but it has different bounds handling IIRC.

Comment: I could rewrite the function from the source code using the numpy.convolve. It works!